# Printing appengine datastore's key_name after querying on user_ID

Tags: google-app-engine, primary-key

The last line of the following code throws the error "AttributeError: 'Notebooks' object has no attribute 'key_name'". I need to produce the key_name result for my app, but cannot figure out how to do so.

```
from google.appengine.api import users
from models import Notebooks
user = users.get_current_user()
user_ID = user.user_id()

print user_ID

notebook = db.Query(Notebooks)
notebook.filter('user =', user_ID)
notebook.filter('deleteRequested =', False)
pages = notebook.fetch(limit=100)

for page in pages:
   print page.user
   print page.key_name
```

My datastore entity looks like this:

```
Edit Entity
Entity Kind  Notebooks
Entity Key   aghkZXZ-ZGVtb3IUCxIJTm90ZWJvb2tzIgVSb2dlcgw
Key Name     Roger
deleteRequested (bool)  

moreinfo (string)   

user 185804764220139124118
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I needed, but even now I cannot find it at the link you gave. I guess I need to learn python <grin>. Thanks, much.

Comment: @Bert, `{% for page in pages %}
<li><a href="/editnotebook/{{ page.key().name() }}">{{  page.key().name() }}</a></li>
</ul>
{% endfor %}` Why does this produce **Could not parse the remainder: '().name()' from 'page.key().name()'** error?

Comment: I was able to workaround the problem with this code: `t = []
     for page in pages:
  t += [page.key().name()]
     pages=t`

Comment: Regarding not finding the answer in the docs link;you get the name of the key from the Key class. To get the key of an entity you call key() on the entity. Then to get the name you call name() on the key... make sense now?  Regarding other question: with standard templating in appengine I think you can say page.key, with no () (in jinja2 templating, page.key().name() will work).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use page.key().name(). (Assuming the key name is on the entity key)

See https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/keyclass

cheers,
Rob